# bugzilla + configure to use microsoft exchange mail server as smtpserver

Tags: smtp, exchange-server, bugzilla

Try to setup bugzilla on linux, below are the setup configuration:

1. CentOS v6.4 32bit
2. Bugzilla v4.2.5

Installation seem ok and bugzilla working, but when configuring bugzilla to send email whenever bug reported/edited, bugzilla just not sending any email out. Below is the configuration on bugzilla administrator > Parameters > Email:

- mail_delivery_method : SMTP
- mailfrom : [valid email address]
- smtpserver : [valid email domain name]
- smtp_username : [valid email address]
- smtp_password : [valid email password]

The smtp server is microsoft exchange server. Whenever I file a new bug, there's a error log created at /var/log/httpd/error_log

> [Tue Apr 30 15:25:25 2013] [error] [client x.x.x.x] [Tue Apr 30
>   15:25:25 2013] post_bug.cgi: Use of uninitialized value
>   $ENV{"FLOCK_FORKING_USE"} in string eq at lib/File/Flock/Forking.pm
>   line 13., referer: http://x.x.x.x/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=Test

No email received at all.

Wonder what's went wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was being solved by my helpful colleague, thanks to him.

Bugzilla come with a mail queuing service call "jobqueue.pl", this service installed automatically during installing the missing components (I believe as I never install this jobqueue.pl manually).

There will be a service installed by bugzilla as well at /etc/init.d/bugzilla.queue.

"jobqueue.pl" and "bugzilla.queue" actually the same thing.

In the bugzilla installation and configuration guide, never mention about this. I didn't check if either service has chkconfig on when start up as I didn't reboot my bugzilla server after installed. So I "chkconfig bugzilla-queue on" manually.

1. If you configured email settings on bugzilla web-admin and tried submitted new bug, then email is created at mysql DB "bugs" > table "ts_job". So first you have to clear out this table first as those data may be not valid.

> DELETE FROM ts_job;

1. Configure administrator > Parameters > Email settings correctly.
2. Run or restart it if already running.

> /etc/init.d/bugzilla-queue start

1. File a new bug will see email send out. But some how still see the error log created at /var/log/httpd/error_log

[Wed May 08 10:19:31 2013] [error] [client x.x.x.x] [Wed May  8 10:19:31 2013] post_bug.cgi: Use of uninitialized value $ENV{"FLOCK_FORKING_USE"} in string eq at lib/File/Flock/Forking.pm line 13., referer: http://x.x.x.x/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi

1. Email can be received finally with the error log above still appear.